# MongoDB HashTable Averages

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using c#,along with MongoDB.
I have a class that can be resembled by this.
Its a sample, that represents something, please dont comment on the class design

```
[CollectionName("Venues")]
public class Venue
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public dictionary<string,object> Properties { get; set; }
}

var venue = new Venue
{
  Name = "Venue 1",
  Properties = new Dictionary<string,object>
  {
    { "Chairs", "18" },
    { "Tables", "4" },
    { "HasWaterfall", true }
  }
}
```

Assuming I have an object in a collection, that looks like that.
I would like to find out of it is possible to do two things.

1: Load from the database, only a single item from the dictionary,
   currently I can only see how this can be done, by loading the entire
   record from the database and then manually getting the value by key.

2: Determine the average of a single item within the database.
   For example, across all records I would like to work out the average
   chairs, again without loading all records and then doing it in memory with
   linq etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your sample document gets stored as a below JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "Name" : "Venue 1",
    "Properties" : {
            "Chairs" : "18",
            "Tables" : "4",
            "HasWaterfall" : true
    }
}
```

This gives you a possibility to define a projection using dot notation:

```
var filter = Builders<Venue>.Filter.Eq(f => f.Name, "Venue 1");
var projection = Builders<Venue>.Projection.Include("Properties.Chairs");

List<BsonDocument> data = Col.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToList();
```

which returns below following BsonDocument:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "Properties" : { "Chairs" : "18" } }
```

To get the average you need to use [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) operator introduced in MongoDB 4.0 to convert your values from string to int. Try:

```
var project = new BsonDocument()
{
    { "chairs", new BsonDocument() { { "$toInt", "$Properties.Chairs" } } }
};

var group = new BsonDocument()
{
    { "_id", "null" },
    { "avg", new BsonDocument() { { "$avg", "$chairs" }  } }
};

var avg = Col.Aggregate().Project(project).Group(group).First();
```

Comment: Brilliant answer and explanation, thank you. 
I see it works great on v4, I am limited to v.3.6, Azure Cosmos DB, but I will try find another implementation for the $toInt which does not exist. Else really great answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternative way of doing it using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) convenience library.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        [Name("Venues")]
        public class Venue : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var venue1 = new Venue
            {
                Name = "Venue 1",
                Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>  {
                    { "Chairs", 28 },
                    { "Tables", 4 },
                    { "HasWaterfall", true }
                }
            };
            venue1.Save();

            var venue2 = new Venue
            {
                Name = "Venue 2",
                Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>  {
                    { "Chairs", 38 },
                    { "Tables", 4 },
                    { "HasWaterfall", true }
                }
            };
            venue2.Save();

            var chairs = DB.Find<Venue, object>()
                           .Match(v => v.Name == "Venue 1")
                           .Project(v => new { ChairCount = v.Properties["Chairs"] })
                           .Execute();

            var avgChairs = DB.Collection<Venue>()
                              .Average(v => (int)v.Properties["Chairs"]);

        }
    }
}
```

results in the following queries being made to the database:

getting chairs in venue 1:

```java
db.runCommand({
    "find": "Venues",
    "filter": {
        "Name": "Venue 1"
    },
    "projection": {
        "Properties.Chairs": NumberInt("1"),
        "_id": NumberInt("0")
    },
    "$db": "test"
})
```

getting average chair count across all venues:

```java
db.Venues.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": NumberInt("1"),
            "__result": {
                "$avg": "$Properties.Chairs"
            }
        }
    }
])
```